# pandas df fill in column names with for loop as variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a df [image: df] and want to fill in the column names from column 3 to the last column (in this case 8 but can be more or less). Starting from 3, two column-names always belong together (in the naming sense) So 3 and 4 are together, 5 and 6 are together .. so on .. maybe sometimes until 20 columns.

So with the following Code:

```
z=1
for i in range(3,len(df.columns)):
    df=df.rename(columns = {i:'searchword %d' % z, i+1:'# of sw %d' % z})
    z=z+1
df
```

i get it to this point:

[image: false df]

But only in the first loop its correct so what i want should look like this:
[image: desired df]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want only to go to every second column:

```
z=1
for i in range(3,len(df.columns), 2):
    df=df.rename(columns = {i:'searchword %d' % z, i+1:'# of sw %d' % z})
    z=z+1
df
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I just had to edit:   "for i in range(3,len(df.columns), 2):"